# Are questions about exoplanets and planetary formation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

In response to this question: ['Late Veneer' on other planets](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2795/late-veneer-on-other-planets?noredirect=1#comment4453_2795)

Few have brought up the point that it may or may not be on topic. Is it?

Comment: Definitely yes.

Comment: Yes, please....

Comment: By the way, related: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2/725

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that it is on topic, it is all about understanding the processes - be it on Earth, or on another planet.  Particularly if we can observe processes that would have implications to Earth-based processes.  For example, the question [Is Mars' mantle homogeneous or heterogeneous and what might this say about mantle convection?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/is-mars-mantle-homogeneous-or-heterogeneous-and-what-might-this-say-about-mantl) at first glance seems to b about Mars, but links the mantle processes to the Earth.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, It is on topic.

This subject is covered every year at the American Geophysical Union(http://sites.agu.org/). I would say that if this question is outside the scope of this website, then, planetary science as a whole is off topic.

If we were to break this question into a simpler, general term, it could be:

Are there Earth like events on other planets?

Comment: If I had enough rep I would expand the AGU abbreviation and add a link. This is an international site.