# Blacklisting the [earth] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There are no longer any questions on the main site tagged with [earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth).  Discussion has taken place [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168/tag-for-global-earth-do-not-use-earth) and consensus is that the [earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth) is not a useful tag.  This site is titled "Earth Science" and that implies every question is inherently about earth, so the tag is unnecessary and conveys no useful information.  Yes, other planets and their processes are on-topic ([here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/are-questions-about-exoplanets-and-planetary-formation-on-topic) and [here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-planetary-science-on-topic)) for this site, and for those questions it is appropriate to use a tag that conveys that they are not about earth, but no such need exists for questions about earth.

Perhaps most detrimental to [earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth) is that alone it tells us nothing useful about a question and this makes it a bad tag.

**I am proposing that we blacklist [earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth) so that it may no longer be used on this site.**

Answer (score 1):

I agree.

[image]